# ARGV is empty in perl script when package is using getopt

Tags: perl, getopt

I'm using `Getopt::Long` to handle the Perl script input, the submodule created is in a package and uses `Getopt::Long` to handle input.

When this submodule is called in a test Perl script, `@ARGV` is empty.

Please help check what's wrong with my script?

When the submodule is not in a package, and called from the shell, `@ARGV` is correct and it works well.

I read through [the `Getopt::Long` documentation](http://metacpan.org/module/Getopt::Long) and googled before asking. Unfortunately I found no answer.

I use the `pass_through` feature of `Getopt::Long` because I want to pass it to a leaf submodule.

```
package getopt_sample;

use Getopt::Long qw(:config pass_through );
use FindBin qw($Bin $Script $Dir $RealBin $RealScript $RealDir);

sub getopt_sample {

    my ( $mode, $mode1, $help );
    $mode           = "";
    $mode1          = "";

    print "$#ARGV\n";
    print "@ARGV\n";

    Getopt::Long::GetOptions(
      "mode=s"              => \$mode,
      "mode1=s"             => \$mode1,
      "help|h"              => \$help
    );

    if ($help) {
        print "help\n";
    }

    print "@ARGV\n";      ### All the remaining unknown options will be left in $ARGV when pass_through
}

1;
```

Perl test script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use lib './';
use getopt_sample;

  &getopt_sample::getopt_sample (
    '-mode'     => "m0",
    '-mode1'    => "m1",
    '-h'
  );
```

Comment: I'm unclear on what is not actually working? Do you want getopt_sample to work with passed parameters, and not use @ARGV if you pass it. Do you want to pass it like you do, or do you want to pass it parsed like you do?

Comment: Seems to work fine here (using Perl v5.20 on Ubuntu 14.10): `test.pl -mode=y a b c` gives output: `3\n-mode=y a b c\na b c`

Comment: @nichola7s: I've made several chnages to your question in an atttempt to understand your meaning. Please would you check that's it's still correct?

Comment: @Borodin, the edit looks OK. I didn't realize that @_ is for subroutine, and getopt only accept ARGV. I attempt to use getopt to handle input for subroutine actually, can getopt use variable rather than ARGV? Thanks, Nicholas

Comment: Test command line:
./test.pl

Answer (score -2):

If you're not finding anything in `@ARGV` when you run your test script, that's because you're not passing any command-line arguments to the test script:

```
$ ./test_script 
-1


$ ./test_script foo bar baz -h
3
foo bar baz -h
help
foo bar baz
```

`&getopt_sample::getopt_sample ('-mode' => "m0", '-mode1' => "m1", '-h');` *does not* add anything to `@ARGV`.  The parameters to a function call are placed in `@_`, not `@ARGV`.

If you want your module to accept input both from `@ARGV` and from parameters that the sub is called with, you can use `@ARGV = (@ARGV, @_);` in the sub to add those params to `@ARGV`.

Also, don't prefix user-defined sub calls with `&`.  It's a Perl 4 practice which is no longer required in Perl 5 and has side-effects which you probably don't know about and, therefore, don't want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I used to use perl for quick and dirty work, and not quite understand the difference of ARGV and @_. After studying the doc, ARGV is from cmd line, shared in main script and subroutine, @_ is for subroutine. That's why my subroutine failed to parse the the input. "@ARGV = (@ARGV, @_);" works if I want to use getopt in subroutine. Is there any graceful way to do same thing? Can getopt accept other variable as input? Maybe other package is prefered to do this kind of thing?

Thanks, Nicholas